# Drop down selection member list

Tags: php, mysql

Where the sent to input is, I want it to be a selection one. I cannot figure out how to make the selection one show usernames that have signed up to my system.

This is how I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbDER.png

This keeps happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpzgZ.png

The code:

```
    <form action="pm.php?mode=sendit" method="post">
    Send To:<br />
  <?
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from usr_users");
  while($m = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  { ?>
        <SELECT name="sendto">
        <OPTION value="<? echo("$m[username]");?>"><? echo("$m[username]");?></OPTION>
    </select>
    <? } ?>
    Message Subject:<br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" /><br /><br />
    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="privmsg" id="new_message" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
<script language="JavaScript">
  generate_wysiwyg('new_message');
</script>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]");?>" name="sentfrom" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question is unclear, I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. Can you explain further?

Comment: Use `select` tag for this. And you have to dynamically generate the `option` tags inside it, via PHP (ie. by querying the db and returning  all usernames and echo-ing it).

Comment: I've tried that, Akhilesha. Keeps giving me a error. Sorry about that GuZzie!

Answer (score 1):

See this http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

Answer (score 0):

You can add users sign session to your databse when they are login, and then select them from your table, and add to option list. If they are logout you delete correct record, or put on cron script which delete sign session records if they are not activity for some time period. This version will be bad, if you have huge system.

When you already made a query to your data base and get them in variable, you should do it something like that:

```
 foreach ($login_user as $item){
  echo '<option value="'.$item['session_id'].'">'.$item['user_name'].'</option>';
 }
```

Comment: you should wrap that script in `<select></select>` html tags, this is a main tag of dropdown menu, option this is a record in your `<select>` menu

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example for you:

```
<?php
    //query the db and select all usernames. Here, I'm just using an array for testing purpose
    $usernames[] = 'abc';
    $usernames[] = 'treyt';
    $usernames[] = 'uiu';
    $usernames[] = 'cvcvb';
    $usernames[] = 'mty';
    $usernames[] = 'opo';

    //so $usernames array holds all usernames now.
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            Username: <select name="user_name">
                        <?php
                        //output the usernames
                        foreach($usernames as $user)
                            echo '<option>' . $user . '</option>';
                        ?>
                    </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if you have lot of users, then I would not suggest this method. Because, the list would be a long one. Instead, you could use AJAX to dynamically display a list of usernames(suggestions), while the user starts typing the name of the user in a text box.

Hope this will help you. :)